# How to redirect error logs to a particular file in python pyramid framework

Tags: python, file, redirect, logging, pyramid

I want to redirect all the logs for my web app to a particular log file

I am looking for one common setting ( code/ini ) that can re-direct all the logs for my app to a particular file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the regular python logging handlers to set up file logging.  See [Pyramid's docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/logging.html) and the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html). For example, here's part of a logger config I've used to set up a rotating file log on the file system:

```
[handler_filelog]
class = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
args = ('/path/to/mylog.log','D', 1, 15)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic
```